# Apply changes to value if List contains duplicates Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a DTO

```
data class ComplexSearchQueryParameter(
        val key: String,
        val value: String,
        val isOneOfMany: Boolean = false
)
```

I have a list  `List<ComplexSearchQueryParameter>` which may contain duplicate keys:  `ComplexSearchQueryParameter.key`

how to check if list contains duplicates and if so change 
      `ComplexSearchQueryParameter.isOneOfMany` parameter to true.

By the way I get List with this method :

```
   return query.split(QUERY_PARAMETERS_DELIMITER).map { queryParameter ->
        val splitedParameterKeyValue = queryParameter.split(QUERY_PARAMETER_KEY_VALUE_DELIMITER)
        val parameterKey = splitedParameterKeyValue.first().substringBefore(QUERY_PARAMETERKEY_SUFFIX)
        val parameterValue = splitedParameterKeyValue.last()

        ComplexSearchQueryParameter(parameterKey, parameterValue)
    }
```

It would be best to apply it here

Comment: `isOneOfMany` is `val`, you can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bananon says, you can't change the values in your list but you can produce a new list with items which only differ in `isOneOfMany`:

```
val list = query.split(QUERY_PARAMETERS_DELIMITER).map { ... } // your current list
val doesKeyHaveDuplicates = list.groupingBy { it.key }.aggregate { _, _: Boolean?, _, first -> !first }
return list.map { it.copy(isOneOfMany = doesKeyHaveDuplicates[it.key] }
```

`doesKeyHaveDuplicates` here will be a `Map<String, Boolean>`, its keys are all `key`s of elements in the original list and the value is `true` if the key has duplicates and `false` otherwise; see [`aggregate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/aggregate.html) documentation to figure out how it works.

Comment: I think `list.groupBy { it.key }.values.flatMap { if (it.size > 1) it.map { query -> query.copy(isOneOfMany = true) } else it }` is more readable.

Comment: @Bananon Though it changes the order of elements which may be acceptable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Kotlin way:

```
val keys = complexSearchQueryParameterList.map { it.key}
            return keys.size != keys.distinct().size
```